# Writing to an existing file without overwriting/erasing

Tags: python, file, newline, writetofile, configobj

My goal is quite simple, but I couldn't find it on the guide for configobj.
When I run my code I want it to write to a file but not erase what there's in the file already.

I would like everytime I run this it should write underneath what's already in the file

This is my current code: That erase/overwrite what's inside the **dasd.ini** already

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

config = ConfigObj()
config.filename = "dasd.ini"
#
config['hey'] = "value1"
config['test'] = "value2"
#
config['another']['them'] = "value4"
#
config.write()
```

Comment: I dont think that it makes much syntactic sense to append to the end of a config file in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your honest opinion, but that doesn't answer my question, if you don't understand what i'm asking for, please tell - so I can edit it.

Comment: I dont understand the use case.  A config file is meant to be parsed in full (that is defiantly what configobj will do, as its what configparser will do).  Appending to the end of the file will result on numerous repeated options appearing over and over again.  and while i believe "last defined wins", it is not how it is intended to work.  Im going to pull a pound-python here and ask - "What are you really trying to do?  what goal are you trying to achieve by bending this module so?"

Comment: I made a function that writes to the file dasd.ini but the values there are going to be written to the file changes everytime I do it so to not lose what I had in the file last time, I want to write underneath what's inside already

Comment: Instead of writing to the file yourself, you should consider using configobj to do ALL the writing.  failing that, you could write both to temp files, then cat them together after they are both written

Comment: Can you show me exampe how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be remarkably simpler if configobj accepted a file-like object instead of a file name.  This is a solution i offered in comments.

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as t1, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as t2, open('dasd.ini', 'w') as fyle:
    config = ConfigObj()
    config.filename = t1.file.name
    config['hey'] = "value1"
    config['test'] = "value2"
    config['another']['them'] = "value4"
    config.write()
    do_your_thing_with_(t2)
    t1.seek(0)
    t2.seek(0)
    fyle.write(t2.read())
    fyle.write(t1.read())
```

Comment: must be an easier way

Comment: what does your function that writes to the file actually do?

Comment: Unfortunately the .write method only takes filenames and not file objects, so I think you have to use temp files to concatenate.  The help file for ConfigObj even says "FIXME:  use StringIO instead of real files."

Comment: StringIO was what I was hoping to use, but this is a workaround for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, doing what you want is a very simple change. Use the following syntax to create your initial config object. This reads in keys and values from the existing file.

`config = ConfigObj("dasd.ini")`

Then you can add new settings or change the existing ones as in your example code.

```
config['hey'] = "value1"
config['test'] = "value2"
```

After you write it out using config.write(), you'll find that your dasd.ini file contains the original and new keys/values merged. It also preserves any comments you had in your original ini file, with new keys/values added to the end of each section.

Check out this link, I found it to be quite helpful: [An Introduction to ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

try it:
You have to read all keys and values of the section if the section existed already
and then write the whole section data

```
# -*- coding: cp950 -*-

import configobj
import os

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# _readINI(ini_file, szSection, szKey)
# read KeyValue from a ini file
# return True/False, KeyValue
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
def _readINI(ini_file, szSection, szKey=None):
    ret = None
    keyvalue = None
    if os.path.exists(ini_file) :
        try:
            config = configobj.ConfigObj(ini_file, encoding='UTF8')
            if not szKey==None :
                keyvalue = config[szSection][szKey]
            else:
                keyvalue = config[szSection]

            ret = True
            print keyvalue
        except Exception, e :
            ret = False

    return ret, keyvalue


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# _writeINI(ini_file, szSection, szKey, szKeyValue):
# write key value into a ini file
# return True/False
# You have to read all keys and values of the section if the section existed already
# and then write the whole section data 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
def _writeINI(ini_file, szSection, szKey, szKeyValue):
    ret = False
    try:
        ret_section = _readINI(ini_file, szSection)

        if not os.path.exists(ini_file) :
            # create a new ini file with cfg header comment
            CreateNewIniFile(ini_file)

        config = configobj.ConfigObj(ini_file, encoding='UTF8')

        if ret_section[1] == None : 
            config[szSection] = {}
        else :
            config[szSection] = ret_section[1]

        config[szSection][szKey] = szKeyValue
        config.write()            

        ret = True
    except Exception, e :
        print str(e)

    return ret


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CreateNewIniFile(ini_file)
# create a new ini with header comment
# return True/False
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
def CreateNewIniFile(ini_file):
    ret = False
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(ini_file) :

            f= open(ini_file,'w+')
            f.write('########################################################\n')
            f.write('# Configuration File for Parallel Settings of Moldex3D #\n')
            f.write('# Please Do Not Modify This File                       #\n')
            f.write('########################################################\n')
            f.write('\n\n')

            f.close()
            ret = True

    except Exception, e :
        print e

    return ret



#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'D:\\settings.cfg'
    _writeINI(path, 'szSection', 'szKey', u'kdk12341 他dkdk')
    _writeINI(path, 'szSection', 'szKey-1', u'kdk123412dk')
    _writeINI(path, 'szSection', 'szKey-2', u'kfffk')
    _writeINI(path, 'szSection', 'szKey-3', u'dhhhhhhhhhhhh')
    _writeINI(path, 'szSection-333', 'ccc', u'555')
    #_writeINI(path, 'szSection-222', '', u'')
    print _readINI(path, 'szSection', 'szKey-2')
    print _readINI(path, 'szSection-222')
    #CreateNewIniFile(path)
```